# C: Parsing a file with fgetc() - EOF infinite loop

Tags: c, parsing, infinite-loop, eof, fgetc

Hello everbody @Stackoverflow,

currently I am trying to write a simple parser for the .obj File format but somehow my parser is stuck in an infinite loop after reading the last comment in my file.txt.
But it also happens in-between.

The parser should do following:

If the current char is a '#' it should print "COMMENT" and skip this line, if it is a 'v' it should print "VERTEX" and skip the line.

Even though I stepped through my code with a debugger I still can't find the problem.

file.txt:

```
# Comment1
# Comment2
# Comment3
v Vertex1
# Comment4
```

Code:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int currentChar=0;

    while(currentChar!=EOF)
    {
        currentChar=fgetc(file);
        printf("CURR CHAR: %c\n", currentChar);
        switch(currentChar)
        {
            case '#':
                {
                    printf("COMMENT\n");
                    currentChar=fgetc(file); //Read Whitespace 1x
                    while(currentChar!='\n')
                        currentChar=fgetc(file);
                    break;
                }
            case 'v':
                {
                    printf("VERTEX\n");
                    currentChar=fgetc(file); //Read Whitespace 1x
                    while(currentChar!='\n')
                        currentChar=fgetc(file);
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I still can not see where the problem lies.

Sincerely,
toxic

Comment: currentChar not initialized before going to while(). Just add  currentChar=fgetc(file); before while

Comment: probbaly not the cause of your problem but testing`currentChar` before it is initialized is wrong.

Comment: @ShihabPullissery I did tet it also with int currentChar=0; before entering the while loop. Still stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @t0XiC This code while(currentChar!='\n')
                        currentChar=fgetc(file); can invoke an infinite loop.

Comment: The solution is probaly a Finite State Machine. (will need 3 of 4 states)

Comment: You test for `EOF` in  the outer `while` loop, but you don't in the inner `while` loop. But anyway joop's comment is appropriate here.

Comment: You are getting loop is it.?? As you have print in your code. look for the last print.! is it "COMMENT"

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @MichaelWalz If the current char is a '#' it should print "COMMENT" and skip this line, if it is a 'v' it should print "VERTEX" and skip the line. Nothing more.

Comment: @t0XiC OK, so you should [edit] your question and put that information _there_. Show the _exact output you expect and make the file.txt: as small as possible but still covering all cases.

Comment: "If the current char is a '#' it should print "COMMENT" and skip this line, if it is a 'v' it should print "VERTEX" and skip the line." merits clarification.  Should code "skip the line" including characters on the same line before it or "skip the _rest_ of the line?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (file == NULL)
  {
    return -1;
  }

  int currentChar = 0;

  while (currentChar != EOF)
  {
    currentChar = fgetc(file);

    if (currentChar == EOF)    // if EOF stop loop immediately,
                               // it's pointless to continue
      break;

    printf("CURR CHAR: %c\n", currentChar);
    switch (currentChar)
    {
      case '#':
      {
        printf("COMMENT\n");
        currentChar = fgetc(file); 
        while (currentChar != EOF && currentChar != '\n')   // skip until \n or EOF
          currentChar = fgetc(file);
        break;
      }
      case 'v':
      {
        printf("VERTEX: <");
        currentChar = fgetc(file);

        while (currentChar != EOF && currentChar != '\n')   // read until \n or EOF
        {
          printf("%c", currentChar);
          currentChar = fgetc(file);
        }

        printf(">\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It's heavily based upon your original code. All comments are mine.

Comment: This works, I will try to understand it, thank you(Vielen Dank!) a lot!

Comment: It's almost your original code, roughly you simply forgot to read the chars that come after the `v`

Answer (score 2):

It’s looks like it’s getting stuck waiting for a newline character. The loop within your switch case is probably the culprit. Change your loop to be:

```
    while(currentChar != EOF && currentChar != '\n')
```

Comment: ... and `currentChar` should be initialized, e.g.: `int currentChar= 0;`

Comment: I tried this, but it won't read my lines with 'v's. It automatically exits the loop after reading the first '#' from file.txt

Comment: @t0XiC of course it doesn't work, you didn't write the code that reads the vertext line

Comment: @t0XiC show us a reproducible example that makes it not work when you initialize it with 0

Comment: @t0XiC you need to resolve this with a a Finite State Machine, everything else will end in tears